# How to place a package on the PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, django, package

I want to add this package to my project https://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html.

The documentation tells me to place the distribution on the PYTHONPATH.

What do they mean and how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: By reading the docs I think you'll be okay with a simple `pip install django-el-pagination`.

Comment: I did that. but for some reason it doesnt really work as it supposed to. So I thought I install the package locally could solve the issue.

Comment: so are you using a virtual environment for your project? after installing the package, you should add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` to your `settings.py`.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What do you mean by 'it doesnt really work as it is supposed to'? `PYTHONPATH` is essentially the directory in which Python searches to import modules so a `pip install` should properly install the module...

Comment: yes. the package is installed and it works... kind of... the problem is that a certain script doesnt behave as it should. maybe if add it to the pythonpath it will work.. :/

Comment: If a certain script isn’t working as you think it should it’s likely the script itself that’s the issue...

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you used `pip` to install the package and you can import it, it is on your `PYTHONPATH`. If your problem is script behavior, `PYTHONPATH` is not your problem and you should explore elsewhere. Consider editing your question to include the unexpected and expected behaviors of your code and the relevant code itself.